# How to manage images in docker registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

As in topic, I would like to somehow manage my docker images in registry. Now every commit sends image to registry, and very fast the space is running low...
Is there any possibility to make some garbage-collector to delete my images with tags older than x ? Or when tags are higher than x ?

I don't need images of my application older than 1 month, but my git only allows me to delete by particular tag, which is not possible when every image has hundreds of tags.

Comment: There some open source solutions, I haven't used them but you can check http://port.us.org/, https://github.com/snagles/docker-registry-manager,  https://github.com/codeabovelab/haven-platform

Comment: Yes, I'm using portus but it allows only to delete by tag or image, and I want to delete all tags older than xx, and it is problem.

Comment: I don't believe the registry server tracks the age of an image, or at least it's not included in the manifest. So programatically that's not possible with the current registry api. If you want to script something without getting too deep in the api, have a look at https://github.com/jessfraz/reg